# $f$ has $n$-order derivative for any $n$ and for each $x$, $ \mid f^{(n)}(x) - f^{(n-1)}(x) \mid < \frac{1}{n^2} $ to show its limit.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

$f$ is defined in $\mathbb{R}$, has $n$-order derivative for any $n$,
and for each $x$,
$$ \mid f^{(n)}(x) - f^{(n-1)}(x) \mid < \frac{1}{n^2} $$
show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f^{(n)}(x) = c \exp(x)$ with constant $c$.

as $n \to \infty$, the $f^{(n)}(x) - f^{(n-1)}(x)$ trends to $0$, it is quite natural to say one of the limits of $f(x)$ is $ c \exp(x)$ intuitively, but I don't know how to exclude the rest and put it mathematically, can someone provide a clue.

Comment: I'd suggest first showing that the sequence is Cauchy, so there exists limit $f(x)$ of $f_n(x) = f^{(n)}(x)$ (it's doable because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} <\infty$). Then, try to prove some properties of $f$. In particular, try to show that $f' = f$. I think you see where this is going.

Comment: In fact, it's uniformly Cauchy so it's uniformly convergent. That might be helpful.

Comment: This will also be helpful in a part of the proof. [Moore-Osgood theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit#Sufficient_condition) We need to switch limits at one point to show that $f' = f$.

Comment: Thanks you for your advice! I am trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f^{(n)}$ converges uniformly to some function $g$. We have $g(x)=g(0)+\int_0^x g(t) dt$  as seen by taking limits in $$f^{(n)}(x)=f^{(n)}(0)+\int_0^x f^{(n+1)}(t) dt$$ . But this equation implies that $g$ is differentiable and $g'=g$. Hence $g(x)=ce^{x}$.

Comment: Thanks this is a good answer!